# Android Studio no puedo representar un valor en otra activity

Tags: android, arraylist, android-adapter

El problema que estoy teniendo es que desde mi clase de *BaseDeDatos* quiero pasar el valor de 3 campos a otra clase llamada *ElegirCuidados*. Logré pasar el valor de dos campos pero no pude con el tercero. El campo en cuestión es el campo "id" de la tabla "reservas", y los dos campos que si pude pasar de la misma tabla son "fecha_ini" y "fecha_fin".

A continuación les dejo mi clase BaseDeDatos:

```
public class BaseDeDatos extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public BaseDeDatos(Context context) {
        super(context, "petshotel.db", null, 8);
    }
    private static final String tabla_pets = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pets(id integer primary key autoincrement, nombre text, edad text, raza text, alergia text, reserva text)";
    private static final String tabla = "pets";
    private static final String tabla_cuidados = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cuidados(id integer primary key autoincrement, reserva text, dia text, turno text, baniar text, pasear text, cortar text, jugar text, comentario text)";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table reservas(id integer primary key autoincrement,usuario integer, nombre text, apellido text, correo text, telefono text, fecha_inicio text, fecha_fin text)");
        db.execSQL("insert into reservas values(1, 1111, 'Rodrigo', 'Paz', 'rodropaz@gmail.com', '1134720205', '2018-01-01', '2018-01-07'), (2, 2222, 'Juan', 'Perez', 'juanperez@gmail.com', '1165478954',  '2018-02-01', '2018-02-05')");
        db.execSQL(tabla_pets);
        db.execSQL(tabla_cuidados);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS reservas");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pets");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cuidados");
        db.execSQL("create table reservas(id integer primary key autoincrement,usuario integer, nombre text, apellido text, correo text, telefono text, fecha_inicio text, fecha_fin text)");
        db.execSQL("insert into reservas values(1, 1111, 'Rodrigo', 'Paz', 'rodropaz@gmail.com', '1134720205', '2018-01-01', '2018-01-07'), (2, 2222, 'Juan', 'Perez', 'juanperez@gmail.com', '1165478954', '2018-02-01', '2018-02-05')");
        db.execSQL(tabla_pets);
        db.execSQL(tabla_cuidados);
    }

    public void insertarPet(Integer id, String nombre, String edad, String raza, String alergia, String reserva) {
        SQLiteDatabase bd = getWritableDatabase();
        if(bd != null){
            bd.execSQL("INSERT INTO pets VALUES(null, '"+nombre+"','"+edad+"','"+raza+"','"+alergia+"', '"+reserva+"')");
            bd.close();
        }
    }

    public void insertarCuidado(Integer id, String reserva, String dia, String turno, String baniar, String pasear, String cortar, String jugar, String comentario) {
        SQLiteDatabase bd = getWritableDatabase();
        if(bd != null){
            bd.execSQL("INSERT INTO cuidados VALUES(null, '"+reserva+"','"+dia+"','"+turno+"','"+baniar+"','"+pasear+"','"+cortar+"','"+jugar+"','"+comentario+"')");
            bd.close();
        }
    }

    public List<Pets> mostrarPets(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM pets", null);
        List<Pets> pets= new ArrayList<>();
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                pets.add(new Pets(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3),
                        cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5)));

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return pets;
    }

    public void eliminarTodo(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM pets;");
        Log.d("Eliminar pet","Datos borrados");
    }

    public Reserva getReserva(String id) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM RESERVAS WHERE id = ?", new String[]{ id });
        Reserva reserva = new Reserva();


        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            reserva.setId(String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(0)));
            reserva.setFecha_inicio(cursor.getString(6));
            reserva.setFecha_fin(cursor.getString(7));


            cursor.close();
            db.close();
        }

        return reserva;
    }
}
```

Abajo de todo en el método *getReserva* es donde agregué arriba de los campos fechas, el campo id para llamarlo en la clase *ElegirCuidados*, el problema es que en *ElegirCuidados* le hago un *Toast* y me en vez de mostrarme el valor de id que llamo, me muestra por algún motivo el valor contenido en la variable *str_reserva* (esta fue una variable provisoria que ahora la quiero sacar para reemplazarla por el valor que quiero traer en el campo "id"), a diferencia de los campos fecha que sí me los muestra correctamente. No se que me estará faltando, esta es la clase *ElegirCuidados* donde lo estoy llamando:

```
public class ElegirCuidados extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String reser;
    String id, fecha_ini, fecha_fin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.elegir_cuidados);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        reser = extras.getString("reserva");

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), reser, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (extras != null) {

            str_reserva = "2";
            Reserva reserva;

            BaseDeDatos bd = new BaseDeDatos(this);
            reserva = bd.getReserva(str_reserva);

            id = reserva.getId();
            fecha_ini = reserva.getFecha_inicio();
            fecha_fin = reserva.getFecha_fin();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            TextView tvDesde = findViewById(R.id.tvDesde);
            tvDesde.setText("Desde: " + fecha_ini);
            TextView tvHasta = findViewById(R.id.tvHasta);
            tvHasta.setText("Hasta: " + fecha_fin);
```

Comment: Pero tu string id lo estas creando arriba, pero nunca lo das un valor por eso es null, debes instanciarlo en algun lugar con el valor que quieres y ya no te mandara el error. PD: No borres el listaRegistro.size();

Comment: El problema no es extras.getString(“”); el problema se encuentra en tu Adapter que mensaje especificamente se muestra?

Comment: son 2 recyclerviews??

Comment: no @armen es uno solo

Comment: si @armen, el "id" también está como String

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que hay un mal entendido en los conceptos

> [getItemCount()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemCount()) Devuelve el número total de elementos en el
>   conjunto de datos retenidos por el adaptador.

Aquí la pregunta es ¿quieres representar los elementos de `listaPets` o de `listaRegistro` ?, se debe definir el únicamente el numero de elementos de una de las dos listas.

Además recuerda que un método no puede retornar dos valores, en este caso solo puede retornar un único valor de tipo `int`.

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {

   return listaPets.size() ;
 //  return listaRegistro.size();
}
```

---

**Si deseas representar los elementos de ambas listas en una sola, lo recomendable es crear un objeto con los atributos de ambas listas y crear una lista de elementos de este tipo de objeto.**

Comment: Gracias por responder! necesito representar los elementos de las dos listas, en principio solo tenia la de listaPets y todo andaba perfecto, pero quise agregar la listaRegistro para representar un elemento de ahí también y ahi es cuando ocurrió el problema. Ya lo corregí y lo dejé como antes mostrando solo los elemtendos de lista Pets. El tema ahora es que no sé cómo hacer para por el boton del adapter pasar el valor "id" de la tabla de registros, para despues éste valor tomarlo en la siguiente activity y trabajar con él

Comment: Hola Rodrigo si deseas representar los elementos de ambas listas en una sola, lo recomendable es crear un objeto con los elementos de ambas listas y crear una lista de elementos de este tipo de objeto.

Comment: Lo que hice fue tratar de obtener el dato de otra manera, me di cuenta que de la tabla de "reservas" (la misma de donde quiero traer el id) ya estoy trayendo dos campos, que son "fecha_ini" y "fecha_fin", asique dije, podría agregar el campo id y traerlo también junto con estos. ¿Cómo traigo los campos fecha? lo edito en la publicación agregando la clase de la BaseDeDatos

Comment: Te sugiero revises [ask] ya que tu edición a la pregunta no hace referencia a nada relacionado a mi respuesta.

Comment: el tema es que traté de hacer lo que me diste en tu respuesta pero no pude, por eso se me ocurrió esta otra manera y por eso el motivo de mi edición

Comment: me puedes guiar con la respuesta que me das? entiendo lo que dices pero no logro realizarlo "Si deseas representar los elementos de ambas listas en una sola, lo recomendable es crear un objeto con los atributos de ambas listas y crear una lista de elementos de este tipo de objeto."